# C program was not written correctly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a little problem in my C application; please help me to reach a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float t[5];
int i;
float *p;

*p=t;

int main (void)
{

    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("t[%d]",i);
        scanf("%f",&t[i]);
    }

    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("t[%d]=%f \n",i,*(p+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program the compiler gives me this problem:

> [Warning] initialization from incompatible pointer type

What does this mean and how can I modify my code so it compiles and runs correctly?

Comment: The code doesn't compile; the `*p = t;` can't appear outside a function.  You might have `float *p = t;` — that would be legitimate.  `*p` is a `float`; `t` degenerates to a `float *`; that's why the compiler complains.

Comment: Also note that for `float t[5];`, it is conventional to write the `for` loops as `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)` rather than using `<=` and 'dimension minus one'.  Ideally, you'd use `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` most of the time — that's more stylistic, and there are reasons not to declare the loop control like that (such as needing to access the value after the loop is complete).

Comment: Also, both `i` and `p` (in particular, and in this example, `t` too) should be local variables.  Use globals only when necessary — avoid them when possible.

Comment: ...that way, if the array length is specified by a constant or a define, the same value can be used for the array definition and for the loop control, by using `<`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot slap some code outside of a function and hope it executes in some order.

```
float t[5];

float *p;
*p=t; // illegal, you probably meant p=t; anyway

float *p = t; // fine

int main (void) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this

```
float t[5];
float *p;
*p=t;
```

will not compile

> **error**: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float’ from type
>   ‘float *’

Do instead:

```
float t[5];
int i;
float* p = t;
```

Comment: But the assignment is still invalid where it is shown outside a function.

Comment: Running the above code generated an error - prog.cpp:7:1: error: 'p' does not name a type
 p=t;

Answer (score 0):

Corrections are commented

```
#include <stdio.h>

float t[5];
int i;
float *p;

*p=t; //here use p=t as *p will dereference it and t is already a pointer type in this assignment both will mismatch

int main (void)
{

for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    printf("t[%d]",i);
    scanf("%f",&t[i]);
}

for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
    printf("t[%d]=%f \n",i,*(p+i));
}

return 0;
}
```